# SVN cannot change ignore property

Tags: svn

I am in Linux. I am trying to add python to my svn. In the end, I found there are many ignored files that were not added to the repository. What I did for this issue as follows:

*$SVN status*                       ----->  result looks fine

*$SVN status --no-ignore*           ----->  list many "I" files ("*.so") and directory ("`__pycache__`")

*$svn propedit svn:ignore .*        ----->  an empty file is open. nothing there. And console shows: "No changes to property 'svn:ignore' on '.'"

*$svn propdel svn:ignore -R*          -----> list a lots of "Attempting to delete **nonexistent** property 'svn:ignore' on ..."

*$SVN status --no-ignore*          -----> still many ignore items, nothing changed

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT:**

My SVN version is version 1.8.10 (r1615264).

Comment: " an empty file is open. nothing there. " The file opens so you can type there. It isn't clear if you do.

Comment: I don't know what to type there. I thought that file is a configuration/property file and I can modify it to remove ignore property from these files/directories.